# Qt: best way to delegate a drag and drop to children

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I'm using drag and drop on QWidget, I have reimplemented dragEnterEvent, dragLeaveEvent, dragMoveEvent and dropEvent, and that works well.

In my QWidget, I have other QWidget children, and I want them to manage drag and drop too. The issue is my parent QWidget catch the dnd events, so my children don't get it. What is the best way to say "when you are above a child widget, the child get the dnd events" ?

Thanks

Edit:

my widgets looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------
|            Parent Widget             |
|       ------------------             |
|       |  Child Widget  |             |
|       |                |             |
|       ------------------             |
|                                      |
----------------------------------------
```

my parent widget and child widget are of the same class.

The code is quite basic, it's similar to this:

```
DnDWidget::DnDWidget(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void DnDWidget::dragEnterEvent (QDragEnterEvent* event )
{
    qDebug() << "dragEnterEvent";
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("foo/bar"))
        event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void DnDWidget::dragMoveEvent (QDragMoveEvent* event )
{
    qDebug() << "dragMoveEvent";
    //do visual feedback stuff
}
```

the dragEnterEvent of my child is never called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [drag-and-drop documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html):

> To be able to receive media dropped on a widget, call `setAcceptDrops(true)` for the widget, and reimplement the `dragEnterEvent()` and `dropEvent()` event handler functions.

Here's the quick summary:

1. The child should call [setAcceptDrops(true)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#acceptDrops-prop).
2. The child should reimplement the [dragEnterEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#dragEnterEvent) and accept its proposed action
3. The child should reimplement the [dropEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#dropEvent) and accept its [proposed action](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdropevent.html#acceptProposedAction).

If any of the above are not true then the parent will have a chance to handle the drop.

Comment: My child do call these methods. The issue is its parent catches the event, so the dragEnterEvent of my child is never called.

So far, I think the solution is to resend events myself through QApplication::sendEvent, but I wonder if there is not a better way.

Comment: The child will see the events first. Make sure that your function signatures match exactly and that the reimplemented methods are being called by the base class as expected.

Comment: Yes it is the case: my child class and my parent class are actually the same. I can see the DnD visual feedback of my parent, and my parent's dragEnterEvent and dragMoveEvent are called, but when I go above a child QWidget, the dragLeaveEvent of my parent isn't called, neither the dragEnterEvent of my child.

Comment: OK, I have found the issue: my child widget was actually inside a QScrollArea. I could see the QScrollArea, but my widget was empty, and I didn't realised it had no size (and so I was never dragging over it). If I put a setMinimumSize, everything works OK. Now I feel stupid :).

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Lol. Thanks for responding honestly :).

Comment: @KalebPederson do you have any idea how to reproduce this when the _child_ is a QGraphicsScene? I can't `setAcceptDrops()` on it... I'm not using a separate class for it either, I'm simply calling it like `scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 600, 500); ` in the parent's constructor.