# Qt: best way to delegate a drag and drop to parent widget

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I have to do the opposite of here:

[Qt: best way to delegate a drag and drop to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209832/qt-best-way-to-delegate-a-drag-and-drop-to-children)

I want that a child widget to delegate its drag-and-drop events in its parent. Is it possible?

My widget looks like too:

```
----------------------------------------
|            Parent Widget             |
|       ------------------             |
|       |  Child Widget  |             |
|       |                |             |
|       ------------------             |
|                                      |
----------------------------------------
```

The parent widget supports drag-and-drop events and its works fine, but it doesn't work dragging over the child widget. I would like all the child widget to delegate their drag-and-drop events to their parents recursevely.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok! I think I have to use event filters for that purpose. http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter

Comment: Yes, I believe you're on the correct path @Andres - I have a very similar situation and am using eventFilters to great effect.

Comment: @Andres, yes eventFilter is 100% the way to go.